# VUE/VITE Problem: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: vue.js, module, typeerror, vite, specifier

I passed last few days on searching the answer to my problem but nothing helps. I deployed my SPA made in Vite/Vue on GH Pages. Locally all works fine, on the deployed page there is an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Deployment by GH Actions. Here is my page: https://pauladanthu.github.io/my-visit-card/

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="style.css">
    <title>Paula Danthu Frontend Dev</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomePage from '../views/HomePage.vue'


const routes = [
    {path: '/my-visit-card/', name: 'HomePage', component: HomePage}
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
const path = require('path')

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  alias:{
    '@' : path.resolve(__dirname, '.src')
  },
  base: '/my-visit-card/',
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

Please help! :)

I didn't try many things because all I found was mostly for react application or vue cli, nothing for vite. I tried adding in index.html this:

```
<script type="importmap">
      { "imports": 
        { "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js" } 
      }
    </script>
```

The initial error disapeared, but new errors occured:

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

GET https://pauladanthu.github.io/my-visit-card/src/router/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I came here because I am facing the same issue. The funny thing in my case is that if the first line of code before the import statement is empty, everything works fine. When the import statement is moved to the first line, I get this error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm facing the same issue, including the load failures due to inconsistent mimetypes in the browser; they crop up when I switch from importing with a relative path import in lieu of a Vite alias import in my client code. For me, the issue started after I did some refactoring of a directory and the SSR rendering code in my app. Few things the issue is not: All the file import locations are correct, an issue with the app itself (works fine in dev mode, which implies this is a build issue – only fails on build. Will post an answer if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I moved the repository to my personal domain, not the one of GitHub, the error disappeared. When I move it back to GitHub domain it comes back. I suppose it’s a problem with paths, but I tried already all possible options (relative, not relative) and it keeps going on. So my solution is to move the repository to the personal domain but it’s not really a solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).